# How to add to component props the HTMLProps types using flow in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-props

I've tried to use flow with React, but found some strange behavior, if I try to include HTMLProps from React to the component Props type, flow throws an error "Cannot get React.HTMLProps because property HTMLProps is missing in module react"

Component:

```js
const Row = (
  {
    jc,
    ai,
    children,
    ...rest
  }: RowProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>
) => (
  <RowW
    justifyContent={jc}
    alignItems={ai}
    {...rest}>
    {children}
  </RowW>
)
```

Flow's error:

```html
Cannot get React.HTMLProps because property HTMLProps is missing in module react [1].

 [1]  2│ import * as React from 'react'
       :
     21│     ai,
     22│     children,
     23│     ...rest
     24│   }: RowProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>
     25│ ) => (
     26│   <RowW
     27│     justifyContent={jc}
```

how can I tell Flow that I want to pass to this component any prop of 'div' element?

Comment: There's no such a thing in flow (only in typescript). You can try to use `HTMLDivElement` instead.

Comment: @AlekseyL. doesn't work, `Cannot create `Row` element because props [1] is incompatible with `HTMLDivElement` [2]. (References: [1] [2])`

Comment: Wrap it with $Shape, to make props optional: `$Shape<HTMLDivElement>`

Comment: @AlekseyL. it works but vscode intellisense has no idea what is the `$Shape<HTMLDivElement>`, and doesn't show me available props. With `React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>` it shows though 

Comment: Do you have flow plugin configured? With `React.HTMLProps` it just picks typescript definitions

Comment: @AlekseyL. I do, but if I define Props like a type `RowProps = { a: string }` vscode gives me a hint when I type  `<Row ...` it shows `(JSX attribute) a: string`, if I add `$Shape<HTMLDivElement>` it removes all of the hints